# getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, mysql

i'm here trying to learn some php but i'm having some problems with my code now i'm trying to solve the "getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty" but there are many others like:/
-Undefined variable: date/
-Undefined variable: imgData /
And yes i've tried other codes and still have the same problem/

So here's my code.

```
     <?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("blah", "blah", "blah", "blah");
    if($link === false){
        die("ERRRO: Não foi possivel a conexão com a base de dados. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }       
            if(!empty($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']) 
         && file_exists($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
        $imgData= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));
    }
            $imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);
            $portal = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field1']);
            $datacri = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field2']);
            $datacri = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date)));
            $datapub = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field3']);
            $datapub = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date)));
            $titulo = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field4']);
            $keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field5']);
            $hashtags = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field6']);
            $pedido = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field7']);
            $autor = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field8']);
    if (!$portal) { 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Preencha todos os campos "); </script>';
    mysqli_close($link);
    }



$sql = "INSERT INTO pedidos (p_portal, p_datacri, p_datapub, p_titulo, p_titulo, p_keywords, p_hashtags, p_imageType, p_imageData, p_pedido, p_autor)
        VALUES('$portal', '$datacri', '$datapub', '$titulo', '$keyword', '$hashtags', '{$imageProperties['mime']}', '{$imgData}', '$pedido', '$autor')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Portal Criado"); </script>';
    } else{
    echo "ERRO: Não foi possivel executar o comando $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
?>
```

And my html file:

```
    <form action="php\pedidos\p_ins.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\pedidos.css">
    <fieldset>
    <legend><span class="number">1</span> Criar Pedido</legend>
    <label for="portal">Portal</label
    <?php                
    $link = mysqli_connect("blah", "blah", "blah", "blah");
    if($link === false){
        die("ERRRO: Não foi possivel a conexão com a base de dados. " . mysqli_connect_error());}
        $result = $link->query("select po_id, po_nome from portais");
        echo "<html>";
        echo "<body>";
        echo "<select name='field1' name='po_id'>";
        echo "<option value=''>----Selecione um Portal----</option>";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            unset($id, $name);
            $id = $row['po_id'];
            $name = $row['po_nome'];
            echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
            }    echo "</select>";
            echo "</body>";
            echo "</html>";?>
            <label>Data de Criação</label>
            <input type="date" name="field2" placeholder="Data de publicacao do Post">
            <label>Data de Publicação</label>
            <input type="date" name="field3" placeholder="Data de publicacao do Post">
            <label>Titulo</label>
            <input type="text" name="field4" placeholder="Insira aqui o Titulo">
            <label>Keywords</label>
            <input type="text" name="field5" placeholder="Insira aqui as Keywords">
            <label>Hashtags</label>
            <input type="text" name="field6" placeholder="Insira aqui as Hashtags">
            <label>Imagem</label>
            <p> </p>
            <input type="file" name="userImage" accept="image/*" class="inputFile"> <p> </p>
            <label>Pedido</label>
            <textarea type="text" name="field7" placeholder="Insira aqui o Pedido"></textarea>
            <label for="autores">Autor</label>
            <?php
                $result = $link->query("SELECT *FROM autores");
                echo "<html>";
                echo "<body>";
                echo "<select name='field8' name='a_id'>";
                echo "<option value=''>----Selecione um autor----</option>";
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    unset($id, $name)
;                  $id = $row['a_id'];
                  $name = $row['a_nome']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
                  }    echo "</select>"; 
                  echo "</body>";   
                  echo "</html>";?> 
                  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />    
                  <div id='footer'> 
                  </div>
                  </form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: where are the form tags? we don't know if that's failing. Obviously something failed, otherwise you wouldn't be getting those `Undefined variable: date/ -Undefined variable: imgData` notices.

Comment: Did you write this code? Why not step by step if you are learning? Now you have a bunch of code and other should fix this? And `getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty` means what it says: The variable that you have given to the function as parameter for the filename was **empty**!

Comment: `p_autor,)` <<< you also have a trailing comma there.

Comment: Without seeing the form tags, it's difficult to solve. Maybe an enctype="multipart/form-data" error, i.e. missing?

Comment: One hint: Why do you not check `!empty($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])` before using `getimagesize()`?

Comment: they post; we answer. They ignore, we leave. I have, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and yes i copied this code but that's because i have a work to deliver tomorrow and i want to finish this quick. And i have the form tags but i didn't copied

Comment: Fred -ii- i was typing but i was also checking code that's why i took some time to answer xd

Comment: @GoncaloPinho had you posted your full code from the start, I'd of solved this in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `input type="file"` is inside a form that has an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` or it will not send to file to your PHP script and `$_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']` will be empty

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="yourphpfile.php">
    <label>Data de Criação</label>
    <input type="date" name="field2" placeholder="Data de publicacao do Post">
    <label>Data de Publicação</label>
    <input type="date" name="field3" placeholder="Data de publicacao do Post">
    <label>Titulo</label>
    <input type="text" name="field4" placeholder="Insira aqui o Titulo">
    <label>Keywords</label>
    <input type="text" name="field5" placeholder="Insira aqui as Keywords">
    <label>Hashtags</label>
    <input type="text" name="field6" placeholder="Insira aqui as Hashtags">
    <label>Imagem</label>
    <p> </p>
    <input type="file" name="userImage" class="inputFile">  <p> </p>
    <label>Pedido</label>
    <textarea type="text" name="field7" placeholder="Insira aqui o Pedido"></textarea>
    <label for="autores">Autor</label>
</form>
```

As for your PHP code, I would advise putting all the block concerning the insert to database inside your `if` block. Plus you have some errors that are fixed here :

```
if(!empty($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']) 
     && file_exists($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
    $imgData= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));
    $imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);
    $portal = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field1']);
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field2']);
    $datacri = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date)));
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field3']);
    $datapub = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date)));
    $titulo = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field4']);
    $keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field5']);
    $hashtags = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field6']);
    $pedido = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field7']);
    $autor = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field8']);
    if (!$portal) { 
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Preencha todos os campos "); </script>';
        mysqli_close($link);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO pedidos (p_portal, p_datacri, p_datapub, p_titulo, p_keywords, p_hashtags, p_imageType, p_imageData, p_pedido, p_autor)
            VALUES('$portal', '$datacri', '$datapub', '$titulo', '$keyword', '$hashtags', '{$imageProperties['mime']}', '{$imgData}', '$pedido', '$autor')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Portal Criado"); </script>';
    } else{
        echo "ERRO: Não foi possivel executar o comando $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
} else {
    echo "ERROR: couldn't get image Data";
}

?>
```

......

Comment: @GoncaloPinho You accepted that answer despite this syntax error? `p_autor,)` <<<

Comment: what do you mean with you accept that answer despite this syntax error , btw im getting another error but with the data i don't know if you help me error "Undefined variable: date " code "$datacri = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date)));"

Comment: @GoncaloPinho ah so now the question isn't completely solved, now you have to live with this answer. You see what I mean? You posted code that contains more errors which I knew from the start. Now you're going to have to wait for the person who gave you this answer, to figure out the rest.

Comment: Well i totally don't know how to work with stackoverflow sorry for reopen the question :/

Comment: @GoncaloPinho Once both `$date` and `$imgData` (undefined) variables have been corrected, you're going to get yet another error and this time it will be due to the trailing comma in your `VALUES`.

Comment: `$date` is undefined because in your code, you get `$_POST['field2']` directly in `$datacri` variable. I will edit my answer

Comment: Well sorry for taking some time to answer im still having some bugs look.http://imgur.com/a/fr9KB I just copied and pasted , and also i did remove that ","

Comment: could you show me the 6 lines you have before the code you copy-pasted ?

Comment: I cant send you here its has more characters than possible and when i use CTRL+K to mark as code it opens me Search google xD

Comment: Now you have my full code and here's the link to the bugs imgur.com/a/fr9KB

Comment: I just solved the data problem but i still have this one "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: Guys i just Solved my whole problem thanks for the help you can now close the question and Ki solved it.

Comment: Good to know :D I'm glad I could help